# Pasar respuesta API a una variable que tiene un array vacio

Tags: api, laravel-8, http-get, livewire

Tengo un componente Livewire en donde hago una solicitud a una API con el verbo GET, lo que busco resolver es pasar el resultado que obtengo de una variable hacia otra. Estoy utilizando la variable de `$response` para guardar la respuesta, esta es la que hace la solicitud a esta API, y como podrán ver tengo una propiedad pública la cuál le asigno un array vacío, es en esta última a la que busco pasarle la respuesta de la API y utilizarla en mi vista dentro de un foreach.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class SearchDropDown extends Component
{
    public $search;
    public $searchResults = [];
    
    public function updatedSearch($newValue)
    {
        $response = Http::get('http://thvid-api.herokuapp.com/videos/game/'.$this->search)->json();
        
        $this->searchResults = $response;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.search-drop-down');
    }
}
```

En la vista Blade y mediante un campo de texto el usuario podrá escribir algo y simultáneamente la solicitud al servidor con el método GET se disparará y así el usuario podrá obtener los resultados en tiempo real.

Si escribo `dd($response)` en la función y me voy a la vista y empiezo a escribir en el campo de búsqueda obtengo los datos correspondientes pero a manera de array.

No he podido mostrar los resultados dentro de la vista utilizando el foreach.

Componente de vista: `livewire.search-drop-down`

```
<input
    wire:model.debounce.300ms="search"
    id="search"
    type="search"
    autocomplete="off"
    placeholder="Type game title or THPS player"
    class="relative top-2 w-full text-white pl-8 p-2 text-sm bg-gray-600 rounded-lg placeholder-gray-400 placeholder-opacity-100"
>
```

Vista donde implemento el foreach

```
                <ul class="h-auto rounded-md p-2 mt-4 mb-4">
                    @foreach($searchResults as $result)
                        <li class="w-full h-20 flex items-center px-2 space-x-4 mb-4 
                                    border-b-2 rounded-sm border-gray-500 border-opacity-40
                                    hover:border-opacity-0 hover:rounded-b-2xl hover:bg-green-500 hover:bg-opacity-70 
                                    transition ease-in-out"
                        >
                            <img 
                                class="p-2"
                                src="{{ $result['Thumbnail'] }}"
                                alt="search results"
                            >
                            <p class="text-sm font-extrabold ">{{ $result['Title'] }}</p>
                            <p class="text-sm">{{ $result['Game'] }}</p>
                            <p class="text-sm">{{ $result['newduration'] }}</p>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví, el problema era que tanto el campo de búsqueda, y el HTML donde se visualizarían los resultados no estaban en el mismo componente.

Entonces desde el componente Blade incluyo el componente Livewire:

```
            <div class="bg-gray-800">
                <div class="p-2">

                    <div class="flex justify-between p-4">
                        <h3 class="font-semibold text-lg italic tracking-wide text-white">Search</h3>
                        <a 
                            href="#" 
                            class="p-2 transition-all duration-200 hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md bg-gray-600"
                        >
                            <svg
                                fill="currentColor"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
                                height="24" 
                                viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
                                width="24"
                            >
                                <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"></path>
                                <path d="M18.3 5.71c-.39-.39-1.02-.39-1.41 0L12 10.59 7.11 5.7c-.39-.39-1.02-.39-1.41 0-.39.39-.39 1.02 0 1.41L10.59 12 5.7 16.89c-.39.39-.39 1.02 0 1.41.39.39 1.02.39 1.41 0L12 13.41l4.89 4.89c.39.39 1.02.39 1.41 0 .39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41L13.41 12l4.89-4.89c.38-.38.38-1.02 0-1.4z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </a> <!-- close button -->
                    </div>
                
                    @livewire('search-drop-down')
                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

Y en el componente Livewire ya puedo hacer mi búsqueda porque ambas cosas estan "conectadas" al mismo componente tipo clase:

```
<div>
    <input
        wire:model.debounce.300ms="search"
        id="search"
        type="search"
        autocomplete="off"
        placeholder="Type game title or THPS player"
        class="relative top-2 w-full text-white pl-8 p-2 text-sm bg-gray-600 rounded-lg placeholder-gray-400 placeholder-opacity-100"
    >
    <svg
        class="absolute ml-1 top-24 text-white"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        height="24" 
        viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
        width="24"
    >
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"></path>
        <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27c1.2-1.4 1.82-3.31 1.48-5.34-.47-2.78-2.79-5-5.59-5.34-4.23-.52-7.79 3.04-7.27 7.27.34 2.8 2.56 5.12 5.34 5.59 2.03.34 3.94-.28 5.34-1.48l.27.28v.79l4.25 4.25c.41.41 1.08.41 1.49 0 .41-.41.41-1.08 0-1.49L15.5 14zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
    </svg>
    <main class="flex items-center flex-col text-white relative ">
        <ul class="h-auto rounded-md p-2 mt-4 mb-4">
            @foreach($searchResults as $result)
                <li class="w-full h-20 flex items-center px-2 space-x-4 mb-4 
                            border-b-2 rounded-sm border-gray-500 border-opacity-40
                            hover:border-opacity-0 hover:rounded-b-2xl hover:bg-green-500 hover:bg-opacity-70 
                            transition ease-in-out"
                >
                    <img 
                        class="p-2 w-8"
                        src="{{ $result['Thumbnail'] }}"
                        alt="search results"
                    >
                    <p class="text-sm font-extrabold ">{{ $result['Title'] }}</p>
                    <p class="text-sm">{{ $result['Game'] }}</p>
                    <p class="text-sm">{{ $result['newduration'] }}</p>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul> <!-- results -->
    </main>
</div>
```

Ambos estan en el mismo lugar, entonces la variable ahora sí corresponde con el `wire:model`